# Map with optional variables as Keys and multiple if elseif condition

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap, apex

Need your help because I'm overthinking a bit. :P
I'm doing a development in apex where we build a Map based on certain keys. Those keys are a mix of multiple variables and so when building a map we have something like:

```
for(rule){
    key = String.isBlank(rule.CompanyRisk) ? '' : rule.CompanyRisk;
    key +=  String.isBlank(rule.PriceType) ? '' : rule.PriceType;
    key +=  String.isBlank(rule.Product) ? '' : rule.Product;
    key +=  String.isBlank(rule.CompanySize) ? '' : rule.CompanySize;
    //..
    map.put(Key, rule.Value);
}
return map;

//and later to get the correct value
for(offerRecord){
String accRisk = offerRecord.CompanyRisk;
String price = offerRecord.PriceType;
String product= offerRecord.Product;
String accSize = offerRecord.CompanySize;

    if(map.contains(accRisk + price + product + accSize)){
        key = accRisk + price + product + accSize;
    }else if(map.contains( accRisk + price + product + '')){
        key = accRisk + price + product + '';
    }else if(map.contains(accRisk + price + '' + accSize)){
        key = accRisk + price + '' + accSize,
    }else if.. //16 conditions now (4 variables as optional)
}
return map.get(key);
```

**Issue:**
Some fields on the key are optional and that happens so the users dont need to create all the rules for all the combinatorions. and when those  optional fields are empty/null it's because it applies for all values of the field.

**Example**: We can have a rule as (LowRisk + Indexed + Computer + Small) with Value=4 and a rule for (Low + Indexed + Computer + '' ) with Value=5 , meaning if the company is small applies the 1st rule but if it it's medium/big/top it applies the one without. Same for the other fields. I can have just one saying (HighRisk + + +) with a value of 0 without the need of specifying all the other criteriums and it applies for all of them.

Because we need to always checking first rules/keys with the optional fields filled, it will become a mess due to a lot of if else.
The conditions are like (ABCD, ABC, ABD, AB, ACD, AC, AD, A, BCD, BC, BD, B, CD, C, D ,'' )

Is there any better solution that could improve this?

I was trying now building some Wrapper class that would return a List for the all combinations and then have a specific method getRuleForRecord() which based on the List (ordered) creates a key from the values of record and checks if map has that key. Not a much prettier aproach. The worst now is building the listOfCombinations on the order I want

```
List<String> keyList = singleton.listOfCombinations;
for (String fieldList : keyList) {
    String mapKey = '';
    for (String field : fieldList.split('_')) {
        mapKey += recordToGetInfoFrom.get(field);
    }
    if (singleton.ruleMap.containsKey(mapKey)) {
        return singleton.remRules.get(mapKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In Java, string literals are delimited by double quotes, i.e. `"`, not single quotes. Further, the `isBlank` method is not static, so expressions like `String.isBlank(rule.C)` are invalid. It’s also unclear why your application needs an `isBlank` check, rather than using empty strings for absent values consistently. Using string concatenation for constructing compound keys can lead to ambiguities, as there is no difference between, e.g. `"ab" + "cd"'` and `"abc" + "d"'`. And it’s horribly inefficient. You are even maxing out the inefficiency by unnecessarily repeating the string concatenation.

Comment: The code is in salesforce´s apex . The quotes we use single instead of doubles. For the String.isblank(x) it's used a static method, I use it here so I dont have NULL as string (like: AnullC)
Sorry for the confusion on abcd: those are just my representation of diferent types of variables in a record and not values itself. If better we can think of rules for Score PriceType + CompanyType. Example rule being (HighScore + Indexed + Big) . I'm editing the question with some better examples

Comment: Then, don’t tag your question with `java` when it isn’t Java. And it doesn’t matter what actual strings you have, it doesn’t change the fact that using concatenation to construct keys can lead to ambiguous keys and is inefficient. Using something like `List.of(a, b, c, d)` has no ambiguities and is more efficient at the same time. But well, that’s Java. Don’t know what the Apex equivalent looks like.